# Gamma Distribution formulas

Tags: gamma-distribution

Why I am finding two formulas for the gamma distribution

The one in my textbook is   {1/(beta)^alpha*gamma(alpha)} * x^alpha-1 * exp(-x/beta)

The one I found on the internet is  {beta^alpha/gamma(alpha)}* x^alpha-1 * exp(-beta*x)

(I have plotted these graphs for specific values of alpha and beta, they are not similar )
are they two different?? if not can you tell why?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi and welcome to Math.SE. For future questions, it would be preferable to use MathJax for mathematical expressions. You can [get started here](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation), and a more complete reference [can be found here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Wikipedia [tells us](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution), Gamma distribution can be formulated in terms of shape $k$ and scale $\theta$, or in terms of shape $\alpha=k$ and rate $\beta = 1/\theta$.

Although, it is atypical to call denote scale with $\beta$, it happens sometimes. Both formulas are the same if you let $\beta \to \beta^{-1}$

Comment: I got it, thank you!